# I am not sure for next sentence using likely

Tags: sentence-construction

In 2040 Supercomputers are  likely to be 30 times more powerful

Comment: Welcome to English language learners. Please make your question clearer. What is the specific problem that you have? Without a clear question, this will be closed.

Comment: "are likely to be" ≈ "probably will be" – so the word _likely_ is used just fine there.

Answer (score 1):

In this context, the word "likely" (the use of which is perfectly reasonable) is used as an informal assessment of *probability.* That is, the author is stating that supercomputers in the year 2040 are *probably* going to be 30 times more powerful. The reason I suggest this is an *informal* characterization is because it is intended to convey a very strong probability, but not necessarily one that can be demonstrated mathematically.